# Do I need to configure anything in MSSQL Server Management Studio to use the SQLSRV driver in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, pdo, sqlsrv

I would like to connect to a local MSSQL server using PDO and the SQLSRV dll. I don't need to build a site or anything huge, it's just for a demonstration. I connect to the local server in MSSQL Management Studio using Windows Authentication. I do not have IIS.

I've installed the SQLSRV dll, edited php.ini correctly, and am connected to the local server. Do I need to do anything else before I attempt trying to connect through a browser, in terms of configuration?

I am running MSSQL Server 2008 R2 and WAMP with PHP 5.3.13

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The MSSQL Server Management Studio has nothing to do with the connection PHP makes using an extension to the server. If you have a successful connection from PHP to the server, then there should be no issue when you try calling your PHP script from a browser (unless your web server is not configured correctly).

Comment: Which DLL should I be using? Should I follow the directions you provided on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16223998/672032 ?

Comment: If you're using Windows Server, then sure.

Comment: No. I'm just on a Windows 7 machine with MSSQL Server 2008 R2 installed. I want to connect to it on WAMP I have installed on the same machine.

Comment: Do I need to do this: Download the latest stable .zip release of VC9 x86 Non Thread Safe from PHP Downloads ? And use:
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll 
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll ?

Comment: Not if you've already established a connection from PHP to SQL Server.